React Native Zeroconf issue with resolving IP address on iOS 17+
I'm facing this issue where the MDNS cannot resolve the IP address when finding the service on a network, this is happening with iOS devices 17+, while with iOS 15 it works ok. I don't have iOS 16 to test it.
As said in the title, I'm working on a React Native project and I use Zeroconf.
This is the error that is shown:
[Error: {
    NSNetServicesErrorCode = "-72007";
    NSNetServicesErrorDomain = 10;
}]

Is there any solution that lets me keep using Zeroconf? If no, which other library I could use apart Zeroconf for mDNS?
I tried to update react-native-zeroconf from "0.13.6" to "0.13.8" but no progress, also the info.plist file should be correctly updated (referring to iOS 14 problem as I read online).
My info.plist:
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
 <array>
  <string>_http._tcp.</string>
  <string>_https._tcp.</string>
 </array>
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add product</string>

Expectation: mDNS able to resolve IP address on iOS 17+
